# I can see through my low poly character's clothes

Tags: solidify-modifier

[image]

I make the suit by duplicate some faces of the body and add the solidify modifier to it. Somehow, I can see through it. How can I fix that?

link to my blender file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aMWmrTZRnbyViD0U6taTERGoQycJf67q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Maybe remove the mesh that is inside the pants, choose a negative Solidify value, use the Data Transfer to transfer the wieght from the legs?

Answer (score 1):

Moonboots was correct, I changed the solidify value to a negative thickness and there don't seem to be any issues now! [image: screencap]

Comment: yeah, it works but can I ask why?

Comment: because you have two meshes that are almost overlapping in the pants, remove the inner one